# Execute query after 1 hour

Tags: php, mysql

Attached the table sample.
[image]

Every hour I want to get the most recent items added to my table.  The table is populated from another source, and I need to track what the last id I received was and get all new items added since.

```
$check5 = "select * from media_ids";
$rs5 = mysqli_query($con,$check5);
if(mysqli_num_rows($rs5)==1)
{
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs5);
$media_id=$row['media_id'];
}

// execute query
```

Comment: Are you running this on a linux server?

Comment: Nope, I'm going to write an answer for you.

Comment: Why in the query you select everything if you're fetching only 1 ?

Comment: I am using third party cronjob

Comment: you can use cron job
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/managing-cron-jobs-with-php--net-19428

Comment: I was testing something else, by select all :)

Comment: @SandeepNambiar Its not about cronjob, main issue how to track which media_id is in progress

Comment: Well there are many ways to accomplish this,do you prefer updating a db column or save it in sort of a text file ?

Comment: @Gal can you suggest something?

Comment: database will probably be more organized but a file will probably work faster but the differences are minor[less then few ms]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You need to create a cronjob that runs hourly.

`crontab -e` and then add `0 * * * * php /path/to/script/script.php`

2. Add a column to your table called `created`, set the type to `TIMESTAMP` set the default value to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

3a. -- Fetch everything in last hour
script.php should look like:

```
<?php

$current = time() - 3600;
$currentMediaQuery = "select media_id from media_ids where created > {$current}"
$mediaQuery = mysqli_query($con, $currentMediaQuery);

if (mysqli_num_rows($mediaQuery) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($mediaQuery)) {
         ... do stuff
    }
}
```

3b.  Fetch 10, maintain a pointer as requested

```
<?php

$lastPointer = “select pointer from pointer_tracking”;
$lastPointerResult = mysqli_query($con, $lastPointer);
$lastPointer = mysqli_fetch_row($lastPointerResult)
$lastPointer = $lastPointer[0];

$currentMediaQuery = “select * from media_ids where id > {$lastPointer} limit {$lastPointer}, {$lastPointer +10}”;

$mediaQuery = mysqli_query($con, $currentMediaQuery);

if (mysqli_num_rows($mediaQuery) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($mediaQuery)) {
        do stuff…
    }
}

if (($lastPointer + 10 > 40) {
    $lastPointer = 1;
} else {
    $lastPointer += 10;
}

mysqli_query($con, “update pointer_tracking set pointer = {$lastPointer}”);
```

You'll need to create a table called pointer_tracker with an id and pointer column, both integer types

Comment: The thing is I am saving the media_id through instagram real time subscription and its dynamic means no of rows will increase, so what happen after 24 if i use date(‘G’)? as comparison.

Comment: Well, it becomes a question of how you want them to correspond to the time right?

Comment: If you have 600 media items, and there's only 24 hours in a day ... which 24 of those 600 do you want displayed?

Comment: What If I execute 10 rows per hour? then second hour next 10? but the question is how I make a script that select 10 next 10

Comment: To be precise I want to select all rows in groups after each hour, since Instagram has api limit.

Comment: Yes, but what do you want to group them BY?  What data point?

Comment: As for selecting 10 at a time, that's easy.  It's all about your query.

Comment: I've updated the sample to show you how to get 10 rows each request

Comment: Suppose I have 40 rows now, First hour first 10 rows(1 to 10), then second hour next 10 rows (11 to 20) then so on? How to track which 10 rows to execute at each hour?

Comment: I get where you're going, the reality is Zack that the possibilities are infinite.  So you need something that scales.  You need to look at what the end result is that you want to accomplish.  You will need to create and store a pointer somewhere, and you'll need to be able to handle different volumes of results.  eg hour one might be 5, hour six might be 9, hour seven might be 10

Comment: By comparing date(‘G’) would it be difficult and complex too? I am not able to understand how I use a pointer and then compare? I want to select the 10 rows per hour, then next 10, but where I use the pointer?

Comment: There you go, I've revised the example to fit with what you want to actually do

Comment: The script gets everything that's been added in the last hour, it then loops through each row returned from the database -- however many that is, and does whatever it is you want to do with the data.

Comment: I am sorry, But its not what I am trying to achieve, I dont want to get whats added in the last hour and executes it, I want to execute the 10 each time and repeat, I have 40 rows now, First hour first 10 rows(1 to 10), then second hour next 10 rows (11 to 20), then if 40 rows completed then starts again from 1 to 10? Your script executes whats added in last hour

Comment: Then you need another table to track the highest id you received in the last fetch of 10, and add `limit {$pointer}, {$pointer+10}` to the end of your query, and if your $pointer value goes over 40, reset the pointer back to 1

Comment: Can you make a sample?

Comment: Done, I added an example for your under 3b

Comment: Thanks, Whats the initial value of $lastpointer? when I create the table and my query will select?

Comment: Arbitrary, set it to whatever you want to start with

Comment: 10 is fine? thats the limit?

Comment: Can you explain what this line will do "where id > {$lastPointer} limit {$lastPointer}, {$lastPointer +10}"

Comment: Where the id of the row is greater than the last id you fetched, and limit the results to be between starting id, and starting id+10

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91235/discussion-between-zack-and-sean).